# making the first image select by default as featured from the modelformset_factory

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I need to make it possible for the first image to be selected as featured by default. Currently it works but only when the user selects the featured image.

Forms.py

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
image = forms.ImageField(label='Image')  
def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['featured'] = forms.BooleanField( widget = forms.RadioSelect(choices=((self.prefix, 'featured'),)))

    class Meta:
    model = Images
    fields = ['image', 'featured', ]
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.text import slugify
# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
body = models.CharField(max_length=400)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
title = instance.post.title
slug = slugify(title)
return "post_images/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)  




class Images(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,
                          verbose_name='Image', )
featured = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

To pre-check the radio button, pass the `checked` attribute to `RadioSelect`. To check an HTML radio button you would use:

```
<input type="radio" checked>
```

where `checked` is a Boolean attribute of the input element. So add an `attrs` dict to set the attribute:

```
widget = forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'checked': 'true'}, choices=((self.prefix, 'featured'),))
```

Comment: Its really working for me, thanks. It was twisting me

Comment: Hey this is really working in a FBV but its showing the checkbox in a Class based view.